# How to open/preview a pdf file from external link?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf, razor

I just want to know how I can open a pdf file online (on my site) using external like . Actually I tried filestream but did not get any result ...

for example I have this pdf file link in my view :

```
<a class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-info" href="@Url.Action("Preview1", "book")" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" itemprop="url">Preview Book <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i></a>
```

and here is my controller code :

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Preview1()
    {


            var fileStream = new FileStream("http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf",
                                          FileMode.Open,
                                          FileAccess.Read
                                      );
            return new FileStreamResult(fileStream, "application/pdf");

    }
```

I got this error :

```
URI formats are not supported.
```

Comment: what is not working ?

Comment: @Shyju I updated my question , have a look please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is on the web, get it has a web content.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
var fileStream = client.OpenRead("http://example.com/file.pdf");
```

Visit
[WebClient at Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Do you know how to add a specific name to the file ? for example when I open this file I see the name on browser is preview , I want to show other name , is that possible ?

Comment: yes, that would be in the response header. Try using HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader(
    "Content-Disposition",
    "attachment; filename=\"myfile.pdf\"");

Comment: Got this error : Code Severity Description Project File Line Suppression State
CS1061 Error 'HttpContextBase' does not contain a definition for 'Current' and no extension method 'Current' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpContextBase' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You using MVC, And probably using the FileStreamResult that has a property named "FileDownloadName"... This means you don't need to mess with the Response headers.
Just do:
 var result = new FileStreamResult(fileStream, "application/pdf");
result.FileDownloadName = "myfile.pdf";
return result;
I never used it this way, but looks just right.

Comment: You are right but it's started downloading and not previewing online and the file name was as you write myfile.pdf

Comment: @Shyju Do you have any idea of this ?

Comment: Since you don't want to download the file, you cant use the FileDownloadName property. Now you realy have to mess with the header.
Try this... (and let me know if it works)
[("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=\"Report.pdf\"")]


You have to add "

Request.Headers.Add("Status Code", id);

Comment: That comment was a bit messy.
Use:
Request.AppendHeader("Content-description", "inline;filename=\"myfile.pdf");
- or -
//Caling from static context 
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader(...); 
 - or - 
Server.Response.AppendHeader(...);
- or -
Response.Headers.Add();